# Dynamically add a row in list view and row contains the progress bar and button in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

i am developing an app in which there is a layout which contains 4 rows in a list view and each row contains a progress bar and a button. Below the list view there is a button when i click on this button, a new row should be add in the list view and when i will add multiple rows then there should be no problem in scrolling up and down. I don't know how to add dynamically rows in list view and how to handle scrolling problem. please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

List view can contain any number of row it depends upon the array of valuew that you provide in its adapter. if you want to add one more value to list add it to its array which you are supplying to its adapter and just call this methods

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You can see one more row is added to your list view